# Asymptotic Notations: (an + b) ∈ O(n^2)

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I was reading Intro to Algorithms, by Thomas H. Corman when I encountered this statement (in Asymptotic Notations)

> when a>0, any linear function an+b is in O(n^2) which is essentially verified by taking c = a + |b| and no = max(1, -b/a)

I can't understand why **O(n^2)** and not **O(n)**. When will **O(n)** upper bound fail.

For example, for `3n+2`, according to the book

```
3n+2 <= (5)n^2    n>=1
```

but this also holds good

```
3n+2 <= 5n    n>=1
```

So why is the upper bound in terms of **n^2**?

Comment: The book also says that the bound `2n^2 = O(n^2)` is tight while `2n = O(n^2)` is not. They use `=` instead of `∈` for reason not yet explained (they say it will be explained later).

Comment: if there is no bound on 'a' then it makes sense to me.

Comment: @MartinSerrano If there is no bound on `a`, it would be O(n*a) or O(n^2*a), but not O(n^2).

Comment: @MartinSerrano Since `a`  is not denoted a function of `n`, one would assume it to be a constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I found the relevant part of the book. Indeed the excerpt comes from the chapter introducing big-O notation and relatives.

The formal definition of the big-O is that the function in question does not grow asymptotically faster than the comparison function. It does not say anything about whether the  function grows asymptotically slower, so:

`f(n) = n` is in `O(n)`, `O(n^2)` and also `O(e^n)` because `n` does not grow asymptotically faster than any of these. But `n` is not in `O(1)`.

Any function in `O(n)` is also in `O(n^2)` and `O(e^n)`.

If you want to describe the tight asymptotic bound, you would use the big-Θ notation, which is introduced just before the big-O notation in the book. `f(n) ∊ Θ(g(n))` means that `f(n)` does not grow asymptotically faster than `g(n)` and the other way around. So `f(n) ∊ Θ(g(n))` is equivalent to `f(n) ∊ O(g(n))` and `g(n) ∊ O(f(n))`.

So `f(n) = n` is in `Θ(n)` but not in `Θ(n^2)` or `Θ(e^n)` or `Θ(1)`.

Another example: `f(n) = n^2 + 2` is in `O(n^3)` but not in `Θ(n^3)`, it is in `Θ(n^2)`.

You need to think of `O(...)` as a set (which is why the set theoretic "element-of"-symbol is used). `O(g(n))` is the set of all functions that do not grow asymptotically faster than `g(n)`, while `Θ(g(n))` is the set of functions that neither grow asymptotically faster nor slower than `g(n)`. So a logical consequence is that `Θ(g(n))` is a subset of `O(g(n))`.

Often `=` is used instead of the `∊` symbol, which really is misleading. It is pure notation and does not share any properties with the actual `=`. For example `1 = O(1)` and `2 = O(1)`, but not `1 = O(1) = 2`. It would be better to avoid using `=` for the big-O notation. Nonetheless you will later see that the `=` notation is useful, for example if you want to express the complexity of rest terms, for example: `f(n) = 2*n^3 + 1/2*n - sqrt(n) + 3 = 2*n^3 + O(n)`, meaning that asymptotically the function behaves like `2*n^3` and the neglected part does asymptotically not grow faster than `n`.

All of this is kind of against the typically usage of big-O notation. You often find the time/memory complexity of an algorithm defined by it, when really it should be defined by big-Θ notation. For example if you have an algorithm in `O(n^2)` and one in `O(n)`, then the first one could actually still be asymptotically faster, because it might also be in `Θ(1)`. The reason for this may sometimes be that a tight Θ-bound does not exist or is not known for given algorithm, so at least the big-O gives you a guarantee that things won't take longer than the given bound. By convention you always try to give the lowest known big-O bound, while this is not formally necessary.

Comment: 'Any function in O(n) is also in O(n^2) and O(e^n).' I disagree with that (or I miss something).

Comment: @Vincent Zgueb Take the definition from your answer. Suppose f(x) is in O(x). Then there is an x_0 and M, such that for all x > x_0: |f(x)| <= M|x|. Now take x_1 = max(1, x_0). Then for all x > x_1: |f(x)| <= M|x| <= M|x^2| and therefore f(x) is by the same definition in O(x^2). I explained the misconception that big-O is a strict bound in my answer, see further down the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations

Comment: I agree that if a function is in `O(n)` then it is also in `O(n^2)` but the way its written in the book is a little misleading, I thought they meant that `an+b` is not in `O(n)`. Can you also explain what "`2n^2 = O(n^2)` is tight while `2n = O(n^2)` is not" means? (Its in **small-oh** notation). Is is because, `2n = O(n)` is tight?

Comment: @Sourabh It might be phrased somewhat unlucky, but the author's whole point was to show that `an+b` is in `O(n^2)` (he wrote that this might be surprising), he never mentioned `O(n)`. Your assumption that from `an+b` in `O(n^2)` it follows `an+b` not in `O(n)` is exactly the misconception he wanted to present. You are confusing me with small-o and big-O notation. Could you please write `o(n^2)` if it is small-o? `2n = o(n^2)` is true, while `2n = o(n)` is not, but `2n = O(n)` and `2n = Theta(n)`. Therefore `g(n) = n` is tight asymptotic bound (up to constant factor) on `f(n) = 2n`.

Comment: No it says "`2n^2 = O(n^2)` is tight while `2n = O(n^2)` is not" (all big-O)

Comment: `2n^2 = O(n^2)` is tight because also `n^2 = O(2n^2)` and therefore `2n^2 = Theta(n^2)`. `2n = O(n^2)` is not tight because `n^2` is not in `O(2n)` and therefore `2n` is not in `Theta(n^2)`. The tight bound is always given by `Theta`. Saying that `O(...)` is tight bound is just avoiding to write `Theta(...)` for some reason, which is exactly what in common use often happens.

Answer (score -1):

The formal definition (from Wikipedia) of the big O notation says that:

> f(x) = O(g(x)) as x → ∞
>
> if and only if there is a positive constant M such that for all
>   sufficiently large values of x, f(x) is at most M multiplied by g(x)
>   in absolute value. That is, f(x) = O(g(x)) if and only if there exists
>   a positive real number M and a real number x0 such that
>
> |f(x)|≤ M|g(x)| for all x > x₀ (mean for x big enough)

In our case, we can easily show that

|an + b| < |an + n| (for n sufficiently big, ie when n > b)

Then |an + b| < (a+1)|n|

Since a+1 is constant (corresponds to M in the formal definition), definitely

**an + b = O(n)**

Your were right to doubt.